# Combining two insert and update sql requests

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, upsert

I have two requests, the first to pressure:

```
INSERT INTO COMMENTS(PRODUCT_ID, USER_NAME, ACTIVE) 
VALUES('1', 'Name', 'false') 
RETURNING COMMENT_ID;
```

Second to update:

```
UPDATE COMMENTS 
SET ACTIVE = true 
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = '1'
```

Do I need to combine them into one request?

Comment: Why don't you just provide `true` in the insert statement?

Comment: Why do you feel a need?

Comment: This will be performed by condition, by default the product is not active.

Comment: I do not know, I want to know whether it is possible or necessary to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `on conflict` clause:

```
INSERT INTO COMMENTS(product_id, user_name, active) 
VALUES('1', 'Name', 'false') 
ON CONFLICT (product_id)
DO
UPDATE SET active = 'true'
```

Comment: This works, but does not change the field `active `